# Ajax post request fails without showing an error, it just prints an empty error

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to create An ajax request in the Django template .. it fails and returns an empty error so am not even able to debug it.

Here is what I tried to do :

***HTML template***

```
.....
                kml_layer.addListener('click', (kmlEvent) => {
                    setMapOnAll(null);
                    var clickedPoint = kmlEvent.latLng;
                    newPoint.postMessage(clickedPoint.lat() + "," + clickedPoint.lng());

                       $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "https://www.{{domain}}{% url 'get_km_from_source' %}",
                            data: {
                                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{% csrf_token %}',
                                layer_id: "{{ single_layer.id }}",
                                the_element_string_id: kmlEvent.featureData.id,
                                clicked_lat: kmlEvent.latLng.lat,
                                clicked_lng: kmlEvent.latLng.lng
                            },   /* Passing the text data */
                            success: function (response) {
                        alert("Thankyou for reaching us out " + response);
                    },        
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // alert the error if any error occured
                        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);

                    }
                        });
                
                });

.....
```

And here is the ***URL*** that is being called.

```py
    path('get_km_from_source/', get_km_from_source, name='get_km_from_source'),
```

Using `print` debugging in the python function that is being called.. it never reaches this point. but it always fails before starting the request .. and it returns an empty based on the lin  `console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);` .. here is how the ***error*** looks like :

```
console output: "error "
```

Comment: Use the network tab in your browser devtools to debug AJAX requests. This will give you the HTTP status code and response text. If it's a 400/500 error you may be better off debugging the server side code first.

Comment: You should check the browser network debug tab and see what kind of request is being made, and see if they look correct. Might need to try to replicate those request with another tool and see if anything is amiss.

Comment: try to log in the error callback : jqXHR.responseText

Comment: this is where a tools like a fiddler https://www.telerik.com/fiddler or https://www.postman.com/ can really come in handy